# Is it possible to place a square image over a oval shape image?

Tags: html, css, image-clipping

I have tried creating a oval shape using CSS and then placing image over it.
 But the background egg shape needs to be an image.
Can I get the same look using image on image? 
So, the background pink shade is an image and the kitty image will be clipped inside the background pink image.
 Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```css
   .wrap {
      background-color: #FCF7FB;
      display: flex;
      align-items:center;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 40em;
      height: 60em;
      margin-top:0.1em;
      margin-left:12em;
      border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% / 60% 60% 40% 40%;
      transform: rotate(170deg) skew(4deg); 
      -webkit-transform: rotate(170deg) skew(4deg); 
   }

   .wrap div {
       display: flex;
       align-items:center;
       transform: rotate(-170deg) skew(-4deg); 
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-170deg) skew(-4deg);
      border-radius: 10%/50%;
      height:60em;
      width:100%;
  }
  .wrap img{
    width:110%;
    margin-left:-2em;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrap">
     <div>
       <img src="http://placekitten.com/1920/780" />
     </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, so you want an `img` element to be oval shape? and another `img` element is display on it but a square shaped `img`?

Comment: Yes exactly..But the square image should look like its clipped inside a oval shape.

Comment: I think you are looking for clip masking here is ref link that may help https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Comment: Then why not just add a background to the container of the `img` like `Every Screamer` answer?

Comment: @VarshaDhadge The oval shape needs to be an <img> and not made using clip-path. So basically, I have an image which looks similar to the background pink oval shape. I want to replace the css with the img so that the output looks the same.

Comment: @Francisaskquestion But that shows a gap between the oval shape and the kitty. Also the corners of the kitty images remain squared.

Comment: Well you can compensate that by adding style to both elements

Comment: @Francisaskquestion But the kitty image is going to be dynamic as well as responsive so I will have to check that too.

Comment: Well it will be depends on your styles, like I said you can customize the styles of the  container and the image.

Comment: I tried the answer of @EveryScreamer answer, and it's working fine, what do you mean that it is going to be dynamic and there will be a gap?

Comment: Using that answer, the kitty covers the entire oval shape.. It should only cover part of it,similar to the current output I had shared

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198578/discussion-between-monisha-and-francis-ask-question).

Answer (score 1):

```
.wrap {
      background:red;
      display: flex;
      align-items:center;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 40em;
      height: 60em;
      margin-top:0.1em;
      margin-left:12em;
      border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% / 60% 60% 40% 40%;
      transform: rotate(170deg) skew(4deg); 
      -webkit-transform: rotate(170deg) skew(4deg); 
   }

    .wrap div {
       display: flex;
       align-items:center;
       transform: rotate(-170deg) skew(-4deg); 
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-170deg) skew(-4deg);
      border-radius: 10%/50%;
      height:60em;
      width:100%;


  }

  .wrap div::after{
    content:"";
    width:110%;
    margin-left:-5%;
    float:left;
    height:60em;
      background: url(http://placekitten.com/1920/780) center center no-repeat;
      background-size:contain;
  }
```

and html

```
<div class="wrap">
   <div>
   </div>
</div>
```